# How to consider only the first element of the tuples in a pandas object

Tags: python, pandas

Let’s say my pandas dataframe has tuples elements in some of its columns and i want to use the method .describe() 
i d like it to consider only the first value of each tuple 
For example my dataframe is:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  6    (5,8)  (4,7)
1  5    (6,3)  (1,2)
2  8    (3,7)  (3,6)
```

And when i’ll use the method

```
df = pd.describe(df)
```

I want it to take for every column with tuples the first value of the tuple to calculate the means and other statistical data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the first elements slicing with the `str` accessor and assigning back:

```
df.assign(**df[['col2','col3']].apply(lambda x: x.str[0])).describe()

           col1      col2      col3
count  3.000000  3.000000  3.000000
mean   6.333333  4.666667  2.666667
std    1.527525  1.527525  1.527525
min    5.000000  3.000000  1.000000
25%    5.500000  4.000000  2.000000
50%    6.000000  5.000000  3.000000
75%    7.000000  5.500000  3.500000
max    8.000000  6.000000  4.000000
```

---

Where:

```
df.assign(**df[['col2','col3']].apply(lambda x: x.str[0]))

   col1  col2  col3
0     6     5     4
1     5     6     1
2     8     3     3
```